# OnCreateViewHolder and OnBindViewHolder not getting called

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

This code was working great few days ago, but now i don't know why OnCreateViewHolder and OnBindViewHolder is not getting called.
Here's my Code :
1st Activity :

```
package com.example.sparshareportappdemo;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button SearchButton;
    EditText SchoolID;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void getSchoolDocBYID(View view){
        SearchButton = findViewById(R.id.Search);
        SchoolID= findViewById(R.id.IDInput);
        String S_ID=SchoolID.getText().toString();
//        Log.d("LMAOO", "Current data: " +S_ID.getClass());
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DisplayRecord.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("School ID", S_ID); //Optional parameters
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
    }
}
```

2nd Activity :

```
package com.example.sparshareportappdemo;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;

import static com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore.getInstance;

public class DisplayRecord extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final FirebaseFirestore db = getInstance();
    private final CollectionReference SchoolColl = db.collection("EM_DEMO2");
    private StudentDataAdapter Adapter;
    TextView Record_Title;
    String S_ID;
    String TAG = "Datacheck";

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_record);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Record_Title = findViewById(R.id.RecordTitle);
        S_ID = intent.getStringExtra(getString(R.string.Schoolid));
        Record_Title.setText("Records of " + S_ID);

        setUpRecyclerView();
    }

    private void setUpRecyclerView(){
        Query query = SchoolColl.document("10th_STD").collection(S_ID);

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Sdm> options=new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Sdm>()
                .setQuery(query,Sdm.class)
                .build();
        Log.d(TAG,"Recyclerview Set.");
        Adapter = new StudentDataAdapter(options);

        Log.d(TAG,"RecyclerviewAdapter Created.");
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.RCView);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(Adapter);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));

        Log.d(TAG,"RecyclerviewAdapter Set.");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Adapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

Adapter :

```
package com.example.sparshareportappdemo;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;

public class StudentDataAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Sdm,StudentDataAdapter.StudentDataHolder> {

    public StudentDataAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Sdm> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull StudentDataHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Sdm model) {
        Log.d("Datacheck","In Onbindviewholder");
        holder.StudentName.setText(model.getStudentname());
        holder.Standard.setText(model.getStandard()+" Standard");
        holder.SchoolID.setText("School Code :"+model.getSchoolid());
        holder.Subject.setText(model.getSubject());
        holder.FormName.setText(model.getFormname());
        holder.Time.setText(model.getTimestamp());
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public StudentDataHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.student_data,parent,false);
        Log.d("Datacheck","In Oncreateviewholder");
        return new StudentDataHolder(view);
    }

    static class StudentDataHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView StudentName;
        TextView Standard;
        TextView Subject;
        TextView SchoolID;
        TextView FormName;
        TextView Time;

        public StudentDataHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            StudentName=itemView.findViewById(R.id.StudentName);
            Standard=itemView.findViewById(R.id.Std);
            Subject=itemView.findViewById(R.id.Sub);
            SchoolID=itemView.findViewById(R.id.SchoolID);
            FormName=itemView.findViewById(R.id.FormName);
            Time=itemView.findViewById(R.id.Timestamp);
        }
    }
}
```

Model Class :

```
package com.example.sparshareportappdemo;

import android.util.Log;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Sdm {
    private HashMap<String, String> QnA;
    private String formname;
    private String schoolid;
    private String standard;
    private String studentname;
    private String subject;
    private Date timestamp;

    public Sdm(){
//        EmptyConstructer
    }

    public Sdm(HashMap qna,String formname,String schoolid,String standard,String studentname,String subject,Timestamp timestamp){
        this.QnA=qna;
        this.formname=formname;
        this.schoolid=schoolid;
        this.standard=standard;
        this.studentname=studentname;
        this.subject=subject;
        this.timestamp=timestamp;
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> getQnA() {
        return QnA;
    }

    public void setQnA(HashMap<String, String> qnA) {
        QnA = qnA;
    }

    public String getFormname() {
        Log.d("Datacheck","Form Name :"+formname);
        return formname;
    }

    public void setFormname(String formname) {
        this.formname = formname;
    }

    public String getSchoolid() {
        Log.d("Datacheck","School Id :"+schoolid);
        return schoolid;
    }

    public void setSchoolid(String schoolid) {
        this.schoolid = schoolid;
    }

    public String getStandard() {
        Log.d("Datacheck","Standard : "+standard);
        return standard;
    }

    public void setStandard(String standard) {
        this.standard = standard;
    }

    public String getStudentname() {
        Log.d("Datacheck","Student : "+studentname);
        return studentname;
    }

    public void setStudentname(String studentname) {
        this.studentname = studentname;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        Log.d("Datacheck","Subject : "+subject);
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public String getTimestamp() {
        Log.d("Datacheck","Timestamp : "+timestamp.toString());
        return timestamp.toString();
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Date timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
}
```

custom data Layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00FFFFFF"
    android:padding="15dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/StudentName"
        android:layout_width="159dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/StudentNAme"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Std"
        android:layout_width="68dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:text="@string/StdVal"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/StudentName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/StudentName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Sub"
        android:layout_width="97dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/SubVal"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Std"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/Std" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/SchoolID"
        android:layout_width="111dp"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
        android:text="@string/SchoolIDVal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/StudentName"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/FormName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Timestamp"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:text="@string/TimeText"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/StudentName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/FormName"
        android:layout_width="201dp"
        android:layout_height="57dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:text="@string/FormVal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Timestamp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/Timestamp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

1st Activity layout xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="273dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:text="@string/Title"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.557"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.143" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        android:text="@string/enter_school_id"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:onClick="getSchoolDocBYID"
        android:text="@string/ButtonText"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/IDInput"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/IDInput" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/IDInput"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="School Id e.g : 445"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

2nd Activity Layout Xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DisplayRecord">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/RCView"
        android:layout_width="410dp"
        android:layout_height="624dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/RecordTitle" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/RecordTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="79dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have put some logs for debugging but the logs from onbindviewholder and oncreateviewholder aren't showing up

Comment: Don't use log statements for debugging. Use debugging tools for debugging https://developer.android.com/studio/debug

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **500 (five hundred)** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.